# How can I check the particular account which has insufficient funds for rent from transaction error

Tags: web3.js, program

I am getting the "Transaction simulation failed: Transaction results in an account (2) without insufficient funds for rent" error while executing the transaction, So how can I check the particular account which required funds for rent?

Comment: Have you tried using a try..catch block to catch the error and log it? Also kindly include more information than this. The cluster you're running on, the code that leads to the error, etc

Comment: Are you asking how to determine which account in the transaction fell short of the rent-exempt minimum balance, or are you asking how to figure out what the rent-exempt minimum balance _is_ for an account of a given size?